# Doctrine 2.0, connect to multiple databases

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm having some trouble on a project.

I'm currently trying to use Doctrine 2.0 for a PHP project.
For your information, i dont have symphony or zend installed.

The server is a MSSQLServer 2008 R2 and i'm using php_pdo_sqlsrv drivers.

My problem is concerning the configuration of my connections.

Indeed, i would have to configure only the connection to the server host and integrate the databases names only in my Entities class.

For my test i've used the following code for connecting, instanciate my EntityManager and fetching my entity:

```
// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_sqlsrv',
    'user'     => 'my_user',
    'password' => 'my_pass',
    'dbname'   => 'dbtest',
    'host' => 'hostname'
);

$config = Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths,     $isDevMode);
$em = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);


$entity = $em->find('myEntity', 1);
echo $entity->getLibelle();
```

And Below, my class Entity

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="tableEntity")
 */
class Entity
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    private $ID_ENTITY;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    private $LIBELLE;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->LIBELLE = $LIBELLE;        
    }

    public function getID_ENTITY()
    {
        return $this->ID_ENTITY;
    }

    public function getLibelle()
    {
        return $this->LIBELLE;
    }
}
```

With this configuration, i've no trouble and my "libelle" is showed without problems.
But What i would like to do (maybe it's a dream ?) is not configurate the dbname, like :

```
// the connection configuration without dbname
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_sqlsrv',
    'user'     => 'my_user',
    'password' => 'my_pass',
    'host' => 'hostname'
);
```

And integrate the dbname in the Entity like, for example, this :

```
/**
* @Entity
* @Table(name="DBNAME.tableEntity")
*/
```

Is there any issue ?
Thank a lot for your help !